# Install webdriver globally or localy?

Tags: webdriver-io

The manual states that

> You can also install the package globally on your machine and use the
>   wdio directly from the command line. However it is recommended to
>   install it per project.

Why is that? What downfall should I worry if installing globally?

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to use webdriver only in your shell regardless of any project then you can install it globally. However, if you wish to use it in a project, such that it is required to run project tests then install it locally (in this case it should be devDependency). The reasons are:

1) When multiple people working on a project, it is ensured that all of them have the same versions of the required packages.

2) Portability. The project dependencies should be completely defined in `package.json` so that after running `npm install` the project is ready to use in every environment.

Answer (score -1):

For people new to NPM and Node, I'd recommend a global install to keep it simple. There are reasons to install it locally though, mostly to do with version compatibility and ease of project sharing: https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/no-more-global-npm-packages/